# IBM IPMI power supply

Tags: ipmi, ibm

I need to work on a customer cluster setup.
I'll go with corosync/pacemaker. I need to setup fencing but all "I" (read: the customer) can offer is IPMI. I am worried about not being able to fence nodes when the power cable is unplugged.
Does anybody have knowledge about IBM IMM ipmi board and can tell me if it has battery backup unit to provide some power at least for a limited amount of time so I can expect fencing agent to complete its tasks? or does it exist as an hardware upgrade on some product lines?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you do an IPMI poweroff the machine _should_ hard power off. You should test this, of course. `ipmitool chassis power off` For extra reassurance, you should also cut power via the PDUs.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for taking sometime to reply. I know ipmi is working. My pb is what will happen if the cable is fully unplugged. For sure the machine will shutdown but the cluster resource manager will try to fence the node because it left the cluster uncleanly. Here is my problem, node fencing will probably fail unless the IBM IMM module has some backup battery, hence my question.